# How do I properly configure SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to work with SQL Server 2005 DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I properly configure SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to work with SQL Server 2005 DB?  The reason I'm asking is because I'm having trouble with and unable to use Integration Services.

Comment: In terms of connecting, the 2k8 Management Studio should have no problems connecting to a 2k5 instance, afraid I'm not that up on integration services though. What errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Move from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008 (This is what I used to move my db from 2005 to 2008)
http://www.packtpub.com/article/moving-a-database-from-sql-server-2005-to-sql-server-2008-in-three-steps

Connect to SQL Server 2005 using Managment Studio 2008
http://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/sql2k8-2k5-comp.aspx

Some more info and tips found here (for trying to connect 2005 to SMS2008) http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Good Luck :)